# Docker image names are changed to sha256 after subsequent runs

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using Docker 20.10.7 on Mac OS and docker-compose to run multiple docker containers.
When I start it for the first time, all the docker images are properly labeled and appear as the following.

[image]

However, after subsequent runs (docker-compose up, docker-compose down), suddenly all the image names are changed to sha256 and start to look like this

[image]

Please advise how to avoid this behavior. Thank you.

UPDATE #1

This is the docker-compose file I use to start containers.
Initially the old displayed with properly labeled image names.
However, not even if I run a `docker system prune` command it continues to label them as `sha256:...`

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  influxdb:
    image: influxdb:1.8
    container_name: influxdb
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
      - "8086:8086"
      - "8090:8090"
      - "2003:2003"
    env_file:
      - 'env.influxdb.properties'
    volumes:
      - /Users/user1/Docker/influxdb/data:/var/lib/influxdb
    restart: unless-stopped

  telegraf:
    image: telegraf:latest
    container_name: telegraf
    links:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./telegraf.conf:/etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    restart: unless-stopped

  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana:latest
    container_name: grafana
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    env_file:
      - 'env.grafana.properties'
    links:
      - influxdb
    volumes:
      - /Users/user1/Docker/grafana/data:/var/lib/grafana
    restart: unless-stopped

  db:
    image: mysql
    container_name: db-container
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: P@ssw0rd
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: P@ssw0rd
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db1
    volumes:
      - /Users/user1/Docker/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
      - "../sql/schema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1.sql"
    healthcheck:
      test: "/usr/bin/mysql --user=root --password=P@ssw0rd --execute \"SHOW DATABASES;\""
      interval: 2s
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 10
    restart: always

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    container_name: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8080

  redis:
    image: bitnami/redis
    container_name: redis
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      #- REDIS_DISABLE_COMMANDS=FLUSHDB,FLUSHALL
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    volumes:
      - '/Users/user1/Docker/redis/data:/bitnami/redis/data'
      - ./redis.conf:/opt/bitnami/redis/mounted-etc/redis.conf
```

Comment: I did not run into the issue myself. Perhaps it is a known problem and someone recognizes it? If not, you might need to add more information. For instance, how are the images build? If you start with a "docker system prune" and then run "docker-compose up --build", do you get the "nice" image names, and then after running it again, the sha256 hashes? Maybe you can sketch your exact steps?

Comment: I am using official images like influxdb, telegraf, grafana, redis and initially they old appeared as image names, but now, even if I run docker system prune it displays them as sha256:... and I am not sure why